# Telegram Bot: как отправить пользователю GIF?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Использую pyTelegramBotAPI. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно отправить пользователю GIF по url из интернета? Если отправляю как `bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, '<ссылка на GIF>')` отправляет просто неподвижную картинку.

Comment: Попробуйте отправить как файл

Comment: Да, действительно! Такая структура работает! bot.send_document(message.chat.id, '<ссылка на GIF>')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294948/telegram-python-chatbot-replying-with-an-animated-gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# указать файл    
img = open('/opt/bot/files/GIF/file.gif', 'rb')
bot.send_video(message.chat.id, img, None, 'Text')
img.close()

# по ссылке
bot.send_video(message.chat.id, 'https://domain.ru/file.gif', None, 'Text')
```

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы он отправлял гиф больше 1 раза? Скиньте код, пожалуйста. Спасибо!

Comment: в смысле больше одного раза? вы можете завернуть отправку в функцию и вызывать её. можете в цикле отправлять подставляя user_id, можете дублировать строки. размытый вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```
photo = open("path\file.gif", 'rb')
bot.send_animation(message.chat.id, photo)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_animation(message.chat.id,r'https://dota2.ru/img/memes/2022/04/74262.gif')
```

я так писал, все работало, у тебя метод фото отправляет, а не гиф.