# Telegram Bot как отправить пользователю GIF?

Tags: python, telebot

Нужна именно загрузка гиф. Ответы что даны тут не подходят [загрузка гиф telebot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/948231/telegram-bot-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E-gif)

Так как они загружают видео, и файл . Мне же нужна именно гиф(проигрывание самой анимации)

```py
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


with open('gif.gif', 'rb') as f:
   image_bytes = f.read()



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome_message(message):
   bot.send_video(message.chat.id, image_bytes)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: А ответы которые тут пробовали? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294948/telegram-python-chatbot-replying-with-an-animated-gif

Answer (score 0):

```
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


with open('gif.gif', 'rb') as f:
   image_bytes = f.read()



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome_message(message):
   bot.send_document(message.chat.id, image_bytes)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: это загрузит gif в виде документа